# Is it possible to temporary only display comments in a word documents?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

It would be easier than just scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Review ribbon, you can turn on the `Reviewing Pane` and select what you see there. From the `Show Markup` drop down, if you only have comments selected, that is all you will see in the `Reviewing Pane`.

[image]

You can re-size the view to cover the page if you like.